# How to remove the gradle nested dependancies, where child and siblings are same

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

I have few dependancies in my project where Child library is same as the sibling library. How do I remove the child? for e.g

```html
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main'.
\--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.3.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.3.RELEASE
     |    \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
     \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
```

So How can I remove/exclude "--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0" who is there asa child element of "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.3.RELEASE" in the tree

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the dependencies you need (presumably using `gradle dependencies`), you can manage your own by setting `transitive` to false:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.3.RELEASE' 
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.7.RELEASE' 
    compile 'aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0' 
}

configurations.compile.transitive = false
```

For example:

```
$ gradle dependencies
compile 
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.3.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.7.RELEASE
\--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
```